# Could there be an upper bound on models?

Tags: logic

For example, if a sentence is satisfiable, is it possible that it has no models of size, say, 4 or greater? I'm thinking it's not possible, but I can't quite see why.

Comment: May be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Totally!

How about the sentence $$"\exists x\exists y\exists z\exists w\forall u(u=x\vee u=y\vee u=z\vee u=w)"?$$ This sentence is true in *exactly* the models of size at most $4$.

In general, any finite set of finite numbers can be the set of sizes of models of some sentence (exercise, using the example above). However, once we move to *infinite* models, the picture changes completely: putting together the compactness theorem and the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem gives us the *full* Löwenheim-Skolem theorem - that if $\varphi$ has *an* infinite model, it has models of *every infinite cardinality*.

(Actually the full Löwenheim-Skolem theorem is broader still - it applies to *theories*, not just sentences.)

---

In a comment, you also asked about languages without equality. In this case, the answer is negative. It's not hard to show that every model of a sentence without equality can be "blown up" - replacing each element with a set of indistinguishable elements. This isn't quite trivial, but it's not too hard and is a good exercise.

Comment: @HughMungus: Without equality you can always pick an element and add however many new elements you want that behave _exactly_ like your chosen one. First-order statements will then not be able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 4):

If it has an infinite model, then it has models of all larger cardinalities (Löwenheim-Skolem). But we can specify bounded-size finite models using a clause of the following form: $$(\exists a, b)(\forall y)(y = a \vee y = b)$$

Comment: Suppose our language has no equality. Then what would happen?